# How can I see a comment on a deleted answer?

Tags: discussion

I've just flagged an answer for [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24226399/) for offensive content, and also replaced the content with...

> (Offensive content removed, pending deletion by mods)

The answer has now been deleted by a mod, and whoever did it left a comment for me.  The only evidence I have is from "Recent Inbox Messages", which starts with...

> @freefaller - editing the post makes it harder to determine the correct flag resolution. Offensiv...

The correct way to deal with offensive content is another question (which I will ask shortly, assuming I can't find an existing question).

What I want to know is how I can see the full comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah - Sorry. That would be my fault.

I didn't double check your rep before commenting and so didn't realise that you wouldn't be able to see the deleted post. Deleted posts are only visible by the post owner and users with > 10k reputation.

The comment was:

> @freefaller - editing the post makes it harder to determine the correct flag resolution. Offensive flags are handled quite quickly so there's no real harm in leaving it intact.

This is also true of spam. By editing it out we have to go and check the post history - just to be sure - whereas if you left the post intact it's often possible to deal with it from the flag queue.

Comment: Ah, fair enough :-)  Thanks for the response Chris

Comment: So it's therefore not possible to see the comment on a deleted post if you're < 10k?

Comment: @freefaller not if it's not your post, no.

Comment: That would make sense.  Would it also make sense therefore that the message should disappear from the "Recent inbox messages"?

Comment: @freefaller , I think it you are right and it should disappear from the "Recent inbox messages" as well.You can start a new discussion about this bug.

Comment: @CoolGuy, [done](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260894)

Comment: Assume you're minus 10 K, and need to see your own comment that's on someone else's deleted answer, what now?