# Remove comment from "Recent inbox messages" if you can't see it

Tags: discussion, bug

This morning I flagged and edited an answer to remove offensive comment.  A mod deleted the answer and left me a comment, but because my rep is < 10k I am unable to see the comment on the deleted answer.  (More details on that can be found in [this META post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260871))

Please can comments on deleted questions/answers be excluded from the "Recent inbox messages" list if you are under 10k, and therefore unable to see them?

I would prefer to not know of their existence, rather than only be able to see the first 100 characters.

---

As an additional "bug", when I follow the link to the comment on the deleted answer, none of the dropdown menu items (All stack exchange sites, recent inbox messages, recent achievements, help centre) work anymore.

I am not making this a bug report on it's own, because if my above suggestion is followed, the problem wouldn't happen.

Here is the link quoted so you can see it (I've tried to add it as an actual link, but for some reason it isn't parsing correctly!)

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24226399/using-javascript-with-asp-net-for-l‌​istbox/24280310?noredirect=1#
```

Comment: What do you see when you click the comment from the "Recent Inbox Messages"? `The author has Voluntarily removed this post` message?

Comment: @CoolGuy, this was a flagged answer, so it goes to the top of the post, with the following URL `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24226399/using-javascript-with-asp-net-for-listbox/24280310?noredirect=1#`.  As a side note, none of the dropdown menus in the header work at this point!

Comment: Oh sorry! I thought it was an question that was deleted...My Bad :(

Comment: Thanks @Frédéric, I'm already aware of the comment, as per the [other META post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260871) I've already linked to

Comment: Ah, I see :) Comment removed, then.

Comment: I have this problem as well, http://puu.sh/9VQ3H/65a1027682.png That is the link and that is the question. Here is the link : http://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/37993547?noredirect=1