# Can I see my comments in a deleted answer given to my question

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-answers

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38078199/autofac-instanceperrequest-created-from-dependencyresolver-current-getservice). There was an answer once. However it was unrelated. After some discussion in the comment section of the answer I've edited my question accordingly for preventing further misunderstandings. Then I want to check those comments again to further edit and clarify my question and then I realise the answer and all the comments with it are deleted.

Is there a way that I can see those comments? Or are they gone?

My question may seen as a duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260871/how-can-i-see-a-comment-on-a-deleted-answer). However there is a difference, in my case I am the OP of the question.

Comment: You'd be able to see the answer at 10k rep - the OP deleted it - presumably they felt their answer was no longer applicable after you'd make your edit...

Comment: I don't think there is normally a way, but I took a screenshot for you: http://i.stack.imgur.com/8VvEX.png

Comment: @zondo There is a difference, in this case I am also the OP of the question